# Active Record & Rails: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've looked up other S.O questions but I don't quite understand how to fix the issue.

Trailers belong_to Movie and Movie has_many Releases. My scope on Trailer:

:released scope intention is to get trailers whose movies have at least one release and are more recent than 25 years:

```
scope :released, -> { 
    joins(movie: :releases).where("movies.release_date > ?", 25.years.ago)
  }
```

Then I have another scope which orders Trailers by their parent Movie imdb_rating:

```
 scope :top_rated, ->  {
        where("movies.imdb_rating IS NOT NULL").order("movies.imdb_rating desc")
```

Now if I call Trailer.released.top_rated, the issue is that the same Trailer shows up multiple times if it's movie has multiple releases. I've tried adding uniq in pretty much every place I can think of, but I just get the error:

```
 ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

How can I show each Trailer only once?

Comment: Did you try taking the first one from the collection like Trailer.released.top_rated.first ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you have used `mysql` then try this way add one more scope like

```
scope :uniq_trailers, ->  {
        group("releases.movie_id") 
}
```

And try to select this way

```
 Trailer.released.top_rated.uniq_trailers
```

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your scopes a bit like this:

**Movie**

```
scope :released, -> { where("release_date > ?", 25.years.ago) }

scope :top_rated, -> { where.not(imdb_rating: nil).order(imdb_rating: :desc) }
```

**Trailer**

```
scope :released_top_related, -> { joins(:movie).merge(Movie.released.top_related) }
```